# How to add intlTelInput in Magento Checkout

Tags: magento2, javascript, magento2.4

**International phone plugin :** [link](https://github.com/MaxMage/international-telephone-input)

**I added in my requirejsconfig.js**

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            customDisplayCheckout: 'Amasty_CheckoutCore/js/custom',
        },
        paths: {
            "intlTelInput": 'Amasty_CheckoutCore/js/intlTelInput',
            "intlTelInputUtils": 'Amasty_CheckoutCore/js/utils'
        },

        shim: {
            'intlTelInput': {
                'deps':['jquery', 'knockout']
            }
        }
    }

};
```

I also added files in specific folders, files loads (I can see it in network in chrome)

**In my onepage.phtml**

```
    require(['jquery', 'intlTelInput'], function($, intlTelInput) {
        
        $( document ).ready(function() {
                                    let input = $("[name='shippingAddress.telephone'] input")

                                    intlTelInput(input, {
                                        // any initialisation options go here
                                    });

        });
    });
```

**This is what I receive in console :**

```
Uncaught TypeError: intlTelInput is not a function
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved

I forgot **window**

```
window.intlTelInput(input, {
     // any initialisation options go here
});
```

I also had another error:

**getAttribute not found.**

I had actually selected two inputs, so check that only one should be selected

Comment: This error occurs when you are in production mode with minify js enabled. I also have this error and am trying to fix it.
Did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If you have **production** mode and **JavaScript minification enabled** then your intlTelInput.js **file is compressed** and minified by Magento, such that the **object keys are changed**.

Go to the page source in your browser and open the intlTelInput.min.js file and compare it to the original intlTelInput.js file (without compression and minification).

I solved this problem by adding the `.min` prefix to the file name (`intlTelInput.js` -> `intlTelInput.min.js`) so that Magento thinks that this file is already compressed and minified and doesn't make changes.

Thumbs up if I have helped.